# Need help changing Title of the page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

I'm trying to change the title by using this code:

```
/* It gets should get the information stored in name */
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Title = $("h2").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("itemprop")=="name"){
            document.title=($(this).html()); 
        }
    });
});
```

It does't work, but how come? I'm capable of getting the information out of the name value, but I'm not able to store it in the title.

I'd want to replace all the information stored inside of the title.

Comment: Please show the HTML too

Comment: $(document).attr("title", "New Title");

Comment: `document.title = "some value"` works fine. It's unclear what the problem is. Maybe nothing in your document matches your IF statement.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. Hint: Show HTML. Also you can remove `var Title = ` anyway

Comment: Need HTML in order to get correct answer as per HTML & Requirement.

Comment: I'm building a website (http://new.cee-platform.com/en/component/advportfoliopro/project/86-printers-publishers/36-burger-zoo-100-year)

And i want the social icons to automatically get the link and title.

I got the link working, but i want to now get the title which is stored in the name variable. Now i want to have the information that is stored in the name variable placed in the title. so it will be added automatically.

Comment: To view the source view-source:http://new.cee-platform.com/en/component/advportfoliopro/project/86-printers-publishers/36-burger-zoo-100-year

Comment: @Notorious_Creed - is the expected result the title becoming "Burger Zoo 100 Year"? ... because it works for me. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/JEMaBoD.png)

Comment: @ImClarky Thank you for your quick response. When you share it for example to facebook instead of it saying "cee-platfrom". it should be saying "Burger Zoo 100 year"

Comment: @Notorious_Creed - In the JS above, try adding: `var addthis_share = {title: document.title};`. [See here](http://www.addthis.com/academy/setting-the-url-title-to-share/)

Comment: @ImClarky I'm sorry, but where should i add this line?

Comment: @Notorious_Creed - perhaps try after `var Title = ... });`

Comment: @ImClarky I've recreated it in JSfiddle if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/sh7tdL5j/4/

Comment: @Notorious_Creed - this is what I mean to add: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh7tdL5j/6/). I think the problem is the addthis script, that you have included in the head, that adds the page title is being run *before* you change the title of the page, hence it stays as `cee-platform`. btw I have no idea if this will work, just a guess

Comment: @ImClarky Thank you so much for the support and help. Unfortunately It still does not seem to work. Like you said the title changes but apparently it does this after it has been loaded in the Addthis script.

I was thinking of removing the title and adding it with JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `document.title` should work. As an alternative you can also use `$("title").html("newtitle");`

I think the problem is, that the code is maybe not executed. Did you tried a console output if your if statement is success?

I think a better Solution would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var title = $("h2[itemprop='name']").html();
    $("title").html(title);
});
```

If there can be multiple h2 with this itemprop attribute then this code has to change a little bit.

Comment: The console does not give any information back so i'm assuming that it has not run into any problems. 

I have tested the code by using $(document.body).append($(this).html()) 

And it prints out the information stored in name on the page.

Now i just want to store it inside of of the title

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).attr('title', 'Hello World')
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    var Title = $("h2").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("itemprop")=="name"){
           $(document).attr('title', 'how would i get the name variable here then?')
        }
    });
});